# Digitally sign files using national ID NFC

Tags: nfc, digital-signature, smartcard, apdu, contactless-smartcard

I am trying to digitally sign files using the signing certificate located on my national ID smart card with NFC. I can digitally sign it over smart card reader, but I am trying to achieve the same thing over NFC.

I'm pretty sure it is implementing the `ISO-7816` standards and `ICAO-9303` (not sure if thats means something), but I am not able to find hardware specifications for concrete APDU-s to digitally sign a file (if it is even possible)

I am able to do PACE authentication and read all the ID data stored inside using [this](https://github.com/AndyQ/NFCPassportReader) project.

What I tried to do as a first step is get number of PIN tries left using the following APDU:

`0x00, 0x20, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00`

But I get `sw1 - 0x6A`, `sw2 - 0x82` which corresponsds to message "File not found".

I am not sure in which direction I should continue.

Also, I should probably mention it is a national ID of an EU country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to digitally sign files using the signing certificate located on my national ID smart card

Machine readable travel document (MRTD) from Doc 9303 doesn't sign files. First of all, it's just a travel document. EU citizen card is different document for different purposes. You better need European Citizen Card specification prCEN 15480 and BSI TR-03110.
There you can find eIDAS Token specification that can deal with eServices, certificates, signatures and so on.